# Why isinstance() not recognising list as a type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very basic but I can't think what I'm doing wrong so hoping maybe it's a syntax change I'm not yet aware of.
This line:

```
if isinstance(x, list):
```

Throws this error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

So why isinstance() not recognising list as a type?

Comment: you probably have assigned the name `list` to a variable earlier in your code. check that, or simply run `print(list)` or `print(type(list))` in the line above to see what the result is

Comment: oooof. yeah that was it. thank you :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably overwritten `list` somewhere in your program:

```
>>> isinstance("", list)
False
>>> list = 123
>>> isinstance("", list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
>>>
```